# JPA 2 Criteria join with abstract collection

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0, criteria

Is there any way to join class Player with Manager in hierarchy as below using Criteria API?
I'd like to find all Players with Manager of given ID in my DAO and tried something like this:

**Query:**

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Player> query = cb.createQuery(Player.class);
Root<Player> root = query.from(Player.class);

Join<Player, PlayerTeam> playerTeamJoin = root.join(Player_.playerTeam);
Join<PlayerTeam, PlayerTeamAssignment> playerTeamAssignmentJoin = playerTeamJoin.join(PlayerTeam_.playerTeamAssignments);

// Desired statement:
Predicate predicate = cb.equal(playerTeamAssignmentJoin.get(ManagerAssignment_.manager), manager);
```

**Class Hierarchy:**

```
@Entity
class Player {
  @OneToOne(mappedBy = "player")
  PlayerTeam playerTeam;
}

@Entity
class PlayerTeam {
  @JoinColumn(name = "PLAYER_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
  Player player;
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "playerTeam")
  Collection<PlayerTeamAssignment> playerTeamAssignments;
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "ASSIGNMENT_TYPE", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public abstract class PlayerTeamAssignment {  // It has three implementations
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "PLAYER_TEAM_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
  PlayerTeam playerTeam;
} 

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("INDIVIDUAL")
public class ManagerAssignment extends PlayerTeamAssignment {
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "MANAGER_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
  Manager manager; // id inside
}
```

Comment: I think your data model may need some reworking.

Comment: Thank you for answer. The thing is that it cannot be modified..
Classes names are simplified for the question purposes - in fact they represent a bit more complicated structure

Comment: Notice that `PlayerTeamAssignment` has no field `manager`. Why not start your query from `ManagerAssignment`, i.e. `SELECT ... FROM ManagerAssignment JOIN ...`?

Comment: Alternatively, you may either include the [`type()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/Path.html#type%28%29) of an entity in your where clause, or, in JPA 2.1, have the provider [`treat()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html#treat-javax.persistence.criteria.Join-java.lang.Class-) the object as a sub-class.

Comment: Once again thank you for your answers! 
I'll try with your suggestions

Answer (score 1):

I already found solution for my problem.
I had to use Path

```
Join<Player, PlayerTeam> playerTeamJoin = root.join(Player_.playerTeam);
Join<PlayerTeam, PlayerTeamAssignment> playerTeamAssignments = root.join(PlayerTeam_.playerTeamAssignments);
Path managerPath = ((Path) playerTeamAssignments.as(ManagerAssignment.class)).get(ManagerAssignment_.manager));
```

and you can use it for example in predicate:

```
 Predicate predicate = cb.equal(managerPath.get(Manager_.globalId), managerId);
```

Comment: I am getting error cannot cast CastFunction to Path